# MP3 to Download-and-Play VS Play-via-Stream - in iPhone

Tags: ios, audio, download, mp3, playback

I have an MP3 on a hosted server. I have to views - each require a different action.

View A : MP3 should Play via Stream from Server (Stream each time)

View B: MP3 should Download  - then play locally (Download once)

(I've got View A working - Streams fine)

View B will not download.

Can someone show me an example?

Comment: You will need to supply more info. What programming language are you using? Have you got any code?

Answer (score 2):

If I am reading your question correctly, there is no way to Download-and-Play an MP3 on iOS.  The only method to "download" is to sync via iTunes.

Safari Mobile will interpret the filetype/mime and if it's a format that is streamable to the iOS foundation, it will override the servers request to download and stream instead (MP3, M4V, MOV, MP4, etc.).

Comment: Ahhh, Thanks Mike! Now I'm understanding more. To Clarify. App is for a Band: View B - We wish to give a song to the end user. (Add an mp3 to the users iTunes). Is this possible? (It starts to look like Apple does not want this to happen.) Am I correct in thinking that I must first wrap the song as a 'PodCast'? Thanks in advance - CM

Comment: Well a PodCast would work in theory but as an end user, I couldn't see myself using it since it would be separate from my music "collection".  The real only way to give a song to the end user would be to have them visit the website from their desktop computer (Mac / Win / Lin) and grab a free copy there.  At that point they can then sync it with iTunes or any other media device they might use.  Best you could do on the iPhone would be to link to the "Buy Now" option if the song is in iTunes.